# Why is Text-Box is not equal Image size?

Tags: html, css, forms, css-selectors

Define me how its issue resolve in which textbox is equal to image. how it resolve.

I make it div to dov images like a navbar dropdown.

You can see everything in this. I tried to resolve it but in vain.

```css
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  max-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<h2>Dropdown Image</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the image below to open the dropdown content.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <img src="Images/forest.png" alt="Tree" width="100" height="50">
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <img src="Images/forest.png" alt="Forest" width="300" height="200">
    <div class="desc">Forest With Road</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not related to the dropdown text, but is caused by the dropdown image overflowing:

CSS defined `.dropdown-content { max-width: 160px }` limits the text width to `160px`, but the image is forced to grow to `300x200px` given inline `<img width="300" height="200">`.

Four options came to mind:

1. Remove `max-width: 160px` from `.dropdown-content`. This will show the dropdown image a its defined *inline* size of 300x200px.
2. Remove the *inline* image `width` and `height` properties as well as  `max-width` and show the image in its original physical size as it is read from the server.
3. Leave `max-width` as is and as an alternative, make sure the dropdown image fits in the defined maximum of `160px` with `img { width: 100%; height: auto }`.
4. As 3. but with `object-fit: cover` instead of `height: auto`.

**snippet**

```css
.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;

    /*    max-width: 160px;/* Alternative 1. and 2. REMOVE */

    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Alternatives */
.max-width  { max-width: 160px }        /* 3. and 4. */
.size       { width: 100%; height: auto }      /* 3. */
.object-fit { width: 100%; object-fit: cover } /* 4. */
```

```html
<h2>Dropdown Image</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the image below to open the dropdown content.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/26/300/200" alt="Tree" width="100" height="50">
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/26/300/200" alt="Forest" width="300" height="200">
        <div class="desc">1) No <b>max-width</b></div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="dropdown">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/26/300/200" alt="Tree" width="100" height="50">
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/26/400/240" alt="Forest">
        <div class="desc">2) No <b>max-width</b> and no inline &lt;img&gt; sizes</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/26/300/200" alt="Tree" width="100" height="50">
    <div class="dropdown-content max-width">
        <img class="size" src="https://picsum.photos/id/26/300/200" alt="Forest" width="300" height="200">
        <div class="desc">3) With <b>max-width</b> and inline &lt;img&gt; sizes, but image forced to fit</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/26/300/200" alt="Tree" width="100" height="50">
    <div class="dropdown-content max-width">
        <img class="object-fit" src="https://picsum.photos/id/26/300/200" alt="Forest" width="300" height="200">
        <div class="desc">4) As 3), but with <b>object-fit</b></div>
    </div>
</div>
```